# What does earning Crystal Points(CP) do for me?

Tags: final-fantasy-airborn-brigade

I've been completing events in *Final Fantasy Airborne Brigade* and earning CP.

I assumed these were similar to the Crystarium Points in *Final Fantasy XIII* in that they were used for character upgrades. This doesn't seem to be the case in this game, however.

**What does earning Crystal Points (CP) do for me?**

Comment: It tends to get you arrested.

Comment: I know that you can get Crystal Point by defeating Atlas as part of the FFXIII-2 Incursion event, but I thought that event ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching through nearly every menu in the game, I finally found it!

**Crystal Points** are used for two things. Your overall leaderboard ranking, and purchasing a small set of items.

Under the **Brigade** menu, if you scroll down to the page, you will see the following:

[image]

Once you select the **Trade** option, you will be taken to the following screen:

[image]

In this menu, you will find **Platinum**, **Gold**, and **Silver Chests**, along with a **Weapon Scroll III (SR)**, and an **Ability Scroll III (SR)**. These items can be purchased using your **Crystal Points**. It is worth mentioning, however, that the cost will increase after your first purchase, but will not raise again after.